# Heaviliy criticized by the senior developer - how to get out of it

Tags: software-development

I am a junior developer, I work in my company from about 1 year and 3 months and I was heavily criticised by my current senior developer, to the point that I start thinking that maybe there is something personal and he has a bias against me that is hard to take away.

Let me explain my story from the beginning: when I started working for my current company (my first job) I felt from little to no pressure at all. The impression was that everything was doing was fine, but this was also because probably nobody was checking my work. I did my best to learn the most I could, but the truth is that there were no expectations from me. During this period it's like if for my company I didn't exist, also because they didn't have a managerial system, there were no official hierarchies. Despite this, I kept growing. During this period of time I received from little to no criticism at all, and after 11 months my current idea was that I was performing well.

After 11 months I changed team, and I was put in the same team with a senior who keep criticising me. First of all I have to say, it was a messy period, we were using beta software and we had to solve a lot of bugs, and so many things went wrong for everyone. Our tools were not working as expected, and I was literally going crazy over bugs and problems we had in our codebase. During this period of time, I often received micro-tasks, and I was often put in the position of having to configure a project in order to clear out a lot of errors, just to write from none to a few lines of code, and then extensively test the application in order to verify that nothing broke, and submit a pull request. I didn't really feel like a programmer during this period of time. I was coding 5% of the time and the rest was testing/configuring/clearing out errors we had in our tools. 
What happened is that I made the mistake of belittling the importance of those things (e.g. checking that everything worked fine after fixing something), also because I was frustrated and I wanted to accelerate testing, to the point that the senior developer in my team criticized me heavily and instead of telling me directly, he directly spoke with the manager and put it like if it's a horrible problem that needed to be fixed, under threat of not getting my contract renewed or even getting fired.

I did what I could in order to improve, and for a period of time I was told by the senior that he noticed some improvement. Despite this, I was literally "downgraded" and put away from my team (probably the reason is that they want to check my work in order to evaluate me better). Right now I am working on little bug fixes on solo, and I report to my senior from time to time. What happened most recently, is that I was criticized again (heavily, with the same threat of not having my contract renewed). The reason behind that is that the senior says that my solutions are not really fixes but workarounds, and that sometimes he expects me to refactor some messy code instead of just fixing the bug that I am supposed to fix (explicitly stated in my task).

Now I looked at the job profiles, I checked and actually it's not competency of a junior to identify and fix technical debt. I can do it, I can even be glad to do it but I don't see why I am being blamed for not doing so when I wasn't explicitly asked to do it. Other than that, if I can make another example, let's say that an application has 40 possible screens. There is a bug that reports some problems in 4 of all the existing screens. I fix it but then someone finds out that the "non-working" screens were 7 instead of 4 (and the other 3 were really hard to catch, they are really edge cases), and I am told that I had to find this out and implement a general solution that worked in all the cases. How bad is this? 
I think that I am being told that I under perform for not fixing some code which is already messy, which was written by mediors and seniors. So why this double standard? why a junior is considered a bad junior for not fixing the mess of the mediors/seniors? which I repeat: it's something that I can do, but I didn't know that I was expected to say: "ok, instead of spending 4 hours to fix a small bug, I'll spend 2 days and do a refactoring".

I just look around my junior/senior colleagues and I don't see that they have to do these things. Sometimes even other seniors apply a quick fix instead of refactoring the existing code. My impression is that this senior is really trying to get me fired, I can see that he criticises everything (even the title of a pull request), and I think that it was the first initial negative impression that I gave him that is now driving him to get me fired. The manager also is not a programmer, he doesn't understand any technical thing, and he always endorses the seniors, no matter what they say. When he hears those things, he only hears 'mistake': he hasn't clear in his mind what is the gravity of those mistakes and if it is something that a junior is supposed to do (and I don't think that he even tries to make this differentiation).

Now my current action point would be to first give this senior the benefit of the doubt and to try improving anything he tells me. For instance from now on I can always present him and the PO with various options, like (a) quick fix that takes a few hours, (a) medium refactoring that takes a couple of days, and (c) major refactoring that takes the whole sprint. I can do more testing and always assume the bug reports are incorrect or incomplete. Then if this doesn't work, my idea is that I go to the manager and tell him that this senior developer isn't being fair with me, and that I want to ask for a second opinion. Another senior can check my work (or I can even be moved in another team), so that the manager can have a second, less biased opinion.

I would try this after 2 weeks / month. What are the other options?

Comment: Is the critism constructive? I think you are taking things too personally

Comment: "The bug was reported for four screens but I found it happened on 7 screens" - with the wrong kind of senior developer you will blamed whatever you do, either for not fixing the problem on the other three screens, or for doing work fixing the problem that you were not asked to do. In that situation, you should enter a separate bug report against the other three bugs. At my place, I'd add the new bug report, link it to the existing one as "related", snd fix it with at the same time as the other one.

Comment: No automated testing?

Comment: One thing I will say is, that when I assign a task to a junior dev to fix a bug, it is absolutely not unreasonable to expect, that if you encounter a code passage that is a shitshow, you do refactor it, not slap a bandaid on fixing a particular bug, but making the codebase even messier and less maintainable. Talk more to your lead. If you find that fixing a bug is associated with changing the structure of the codebase and that this takes a lot of time, you need to communicate that. I don't expect juniors to do large refactoring, but I do expect avoiding crappy patchwork to fix X.

Comment: You seem to be approaching this from the perspective of a "what a junior should do", rather than thinking about what your company/team/project *needs*.   Likely the near term solution is more communication with your supervisor - analyze a situation and ask for advice on courses of action.  Seek clarity if you should do housekeeping along the way to fixing a specific issue and if yes, if that should be in a separate commit or intermixed in with the issue fix, etc.  If you think an issue might be more widespread, suggest at standup you'll spend some time checking for that, etc...

Comment: @dan-klasson Unfortunately the mentality of this company is "if you don't know how to do x, you shouldn't do x". Now the fact is that we don't have automated tests, and I know how to write them. But convincing the senior and the manager that I know how to write them would be very hard. So they delegated the work of writing automated testing to the most senior developer (not the one I work with), and it will take very long time. With the malus that people who don't know how to write automated tests will never learn it (same for other concepts, who doesn't know x is prevented from learning x).

Comment: Why is this question off topic? I am already explaining which is my current strategy (check the last paragraph before my question), and it's clear that I am asking if I have more valuable options.

Answer (score 5):

I know it's not what you want to hear, but you're learning what professional development actually is .

> I was often put in the position of having to configure a project in order to clear out a lot of errors, just to write from none to a few lines of code, and then extensively test the application in order to verify that nothing broke, and submit a pull request. I didn't really feel like a programmer during this period of time

This is one of the most valuable things a professional developer can actually do for their employer. You added a ton of value to the organisation during this period. I also don't find this kind of work satisfying, but it is literally the most important thing to do in order to mitigate a situation like:

> Our tools were not working as expected, and I was literally going crazy over bugs and problems we had in our codebase.

This is a terrible situation for a company to be in. Their products don't work and are actively damaging the company's reputation, and they need to spend money fixing something they should have done right the first time instead of improving the value of the products they make.

> Now I looked at the job profiles, I checked and actually it's not competency of a junior to identify and fix technical debt.

Sorry, but you're not right here. Any competent developer should *always* be doing this.

There's no easy way out of your situation, because you're going through the process of learning what's required to be more senior in your profession. It's not always fun, quick wins. Sorry about that, I know it sucks. For what it's worth, it sounds to me like the senior who you perceive as hurting you is actually grooming you for promotion and more responsibility, if you're able to step up and meet the challenges you're facing.

Comment: Indeed, resolving build issues is important and useful.  Such fixes typically deserve to be their own commits and pull requests, distinct from logic changes and functional bugfixes, as each needs a different type of review and strategic evaluation especially if there is any dilemma as to if/when/how it should apply.  And yes, in being distinct they may get more social credit as contributions.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think he is grooming me for a promotion and more responsibility. In the best case scenario I would be not fired. What I can hope for is that I have a really chance to improve myself and demonstrate it, so I am going to give it a try. But if I find out that whatever I do it's wrong I'll have to speak with the manager.

Comment: @BohBoh he may not _think_ he is, but even if he has malicious intentions then stepping up, meeting the challenges and learning from them will make you a better developer. He will have accidentally helped your career in that case.

Answer (score 3):

> There is a bug that reports some problems in 4 of all the existing screens. I fix it but then someone finds out that the "non-working" screens were 7 instead of 4 (and the other 3 were really hard to catch, they are really edge cases), and I am told that I had to find this out and implement a general solution that worked in all the cases.

If the problem had a root cause you didn't even *try* to identify, you missed some part of the job. A bug must first be reproduced, understood, then fixed. It could take you extra time, but the quickest fix is not always the best fix. Otherwise, the report should be a fine arbiter, you could simply point out the other 3 weren't listed.

> ok, instead of spending 4 hours to fix a small bug, I'll spend 2 days and do a refactoring

It's not about refactoring, refactoring make things work the same, here it's about fixing a bug. Fixing bugs can be hard and time-consuming when done properly. I know bugs that took days, sometimes weeks to fix. The management usually knows that, they want you to take the time it takes. They usually get more satisfied by a warning when you are a middle of it that "it will take longer than expected" than you finding a quick patch that is not going to cover the bug in full.

> I can see that he criticises everything (even the title of a pull request), and I think that it was the first initial negative impression that I gave him that is now driving him to get me fired

In any work environment you will find people that lack tact when they give feedback. For what it's worth I've crossed path of fine specimens that could snap at you for things like a trailing white space in a pull request, and usually rewrote every variable name of what you handed to them to fit their standards of quality.

But it doesn't take long for people like this to be identified as having high standards (if not worse). Nobody will think you deserve a bad performance review because you have a bad habit of leaving trailing white spaces. Don't take managers and seniors for fools, they can tell in the long run the difference between an apt, growing and learning recruit, and inept recruit. Unless your manager had talked about your performance in 1 on 1, you are probably overestimating the danger you are in.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to ather to Player One's and Arthur Havlicek's answer (both are good).

Your Senior developer is propably a good technical person but lacks person skill training. It's important to realise that it is like that in 99% of all companies.
So decoding his messages might be hard, especially if you are not used to that.

Good teams have culture, great teams make it explicit:
You stumble around and try to learn the culture, and they are annoyed you don't already know that. Stuff like: Yeah, fix that bug. Then but some refactoring on top.
You were never told that, now that you are told. Do it next time.
If you want to be golden, try to push for a team guideline.
You could say something like: "Sorry, I didn't know. Now that I know, I will do it. It would be helpful for new teammembers to know how things work around here, I'd like to start a wikipage with stuff like that. Where shall I put it?"

This way, you show will to improve yourself AND the team.

Regarding the quick fix, there are several things at work here:

- not every older member behaves senior. And even truly senior members can lapse from time to time. We hould ourselves to perfection on the way to get better, knowing we can never reach perfection.
- someone more senior has a better judgement which quickfixes are acceptable, and which aren't, regarding impact, affected systems and the like.
- if you think you have a quickfix, ask someone if they want it fast or right. If the answer is fast every time, all the time, switch companies because it will go down the technical debt hell hole at some point. But it's perfectly normal that it's fast instead of right some times.

Also, I'd like to think that critcizing you is a sign in believing you can and will improve. At my first company, there was one super critical guy who found a lot of bad things to say about the stuff about I do. When I left after 2 years, he said about me I am a competent developer and it's a loss to the company. That was the first praise in 2 years. And he only told others after I left, he never told me directly.
Some people just aren't used to giving praise.

Also, I had some people in my past i gave up criticizing. If I've had the chance, I would have fired them immediatly. But we were just on the same level, so I stopped interacting to the best of my abilities. (After several fruitless attempts of change).
And I wasn't the only one behaving like that. So if criticism is replaced by silence, THEN start worrying. If you actively ask how to improve, you won't be in that situation. But if you ever are, start asking for criticism. It's the only way out.

Comment: I would be tempted to think that he is only trying to "squeeze" me in order to get the best out of me. But now the worrying part is that I am under threat of not having my contract renewed, so my doubt is if it's just about improving myself, or if he has decided in his mind that I should get fired and he is openly criticizing me only to convince the manager. In any case I will give it a try, but in the worst case scenario if things will turn to an irrecoverable point, do you think that it would be wise to ask for a second opinion (of another senior), claiming that he is not fair to me?

Comment: you could look something up like a Nonviloent communication video and talk to the senior directly. Id do that, but that may be to direct for you. But getting a 2nd opinion can help, hopefully somebody who has a good judge of character and can be neutral. But totally do that BEFORE it turns irrecoverable. Maybe somebody inside your organization can give more specific insight/advice

Comment: also, if you ask somebody else, maybe dont start with the claim, but start with some like: Senior X points out my errors in a lot of instances, and I feel quite down. I am afraid that will impact my evaluation, what do you think of all that?
If somebody does something bad, you can either assume incompetence or bad intent. Assmuning incompetence is often the better approach, because it gives the other person an easier way out.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the senior is frustrated, not necessarily with just you. Weather the storm, do your best and keep your head down until it either passes or becomes untenable. Then you will have narrowed your options down much more.

Right now it's not clear enough to do more than that unless you want to quit, in which case start job hunting.

In terms of the work, that's how you learn, you do the mundane tasks again and again until doing them properly is second nature. Then in a few years as a senior you get to drum them into a juniors head and you'll remember why and how hard it was to make it stick.